# MSBuild - can it work out project dependencies in a solution file? If so how?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I have an msbuild project which builds a SLN file from visual studio which holds all the projects in (about 70+ project), and a lot of the projects are dependent on each other meaning they need to be build in order - sometimes a developer forgets to set the build order manually in visual studio in the solution file causing the msbuild on a clean solution to fail as something gets built out of order/cant find a dll.

Is there a way for msbuild to take all projects and work out the dependencies and build the projects in order, if there is how do i do this? using an MSBuild task? With current tries it seems to just build in the order it reads the projects in - if i pass in a list of project files+paths.

Currently the only way i can think to solve this is a external app which scans the proj files and references and then manually creates a solution each time.. but this seems overkill for such a simple thing.

Anyone solved / seen this before?

Comment: can you elaborate on what you mean by developers not setting the build order manually in VS?

Comment: Is this your problem? It's currently giving me trouble. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/msbuild/thread/80cc6447-b720-4806-8395-7c257b207613?prof=required There doesn't seem to be a great solution. I think we're going to write a tool to parse through the .sln file, look in the referenced .csproj files for the <ProjectReference> tags, and copy that info back into the .sln file.

Answer (score 5):

While Project Dependencies are hard to maintain and not shared across .sln files, Project *References* are honoured and do dictate the order consistently - see the `ResolveReferences` task in `Microsoft.Common.targets`.

ASIDE: A 'friend of mine' may 'during a refactoring' have accidentally stubbed out their Build `Task` and it's `DependsOnTargets` linkage to the `Microsoft.Common.targets` `ResolveReferences` task and ended up with `ProjectReferences` not being honoured in ways that sound like the question here. If you [read some of the posts](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/msbuild/thread/80cc6447-b720-4806-8395-7c257b207613?prof=required), you might get the idea that it's all mad shaky - it's not; the shaky bits are the Project *dependencies*, not the Project *references*.

---

See [this excellent MSDN Blog article by Dan Moseley](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msbuild/archive/2010/12/21/incorrect-solution-build-ordering-when-using-msbuild-exe.aspx) that really explains the topic, including some useful workaround strategies. (via [this mildly related issue with building xUnit.net](http://xunit.codeplex.com/discussions/354418)).

Answer (score 4):

How are you calling MSBuild? If you point MSBuild to the solution file, it should be able to work out the dependencies. If you point it to individual project files, then it won't be able to resolve any project references.

If you don't use project references you can still control the dependency order in a solution by using the "Project Dependencies" dialog to manually set the dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

If all of your dependent projects are in the solution and you are using Project references, Visual Studio should manage the dependencies for your and build in order of that dependency list.

It sounds like you are not using project references.  I always recommend project references.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but the issue was most likely that projects in the solution used direct references to dependent DLLs (Add Reference > select Browse tab > select dependent DLL) instead of using project references (Add Reference > select Projects tab > select dependent project). With direct references, Visual Studio can't figure out the dependency chain. You must tell it by right clicking on the solution node and select Properties. Pick Common Properties > Project Dependencies to set the required projects. Mr. Klaus is correct but I wanted to document how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

While it is correct that MSBuild should observe the build order when you use project dependencies there is one caveat. It doesn't at present observe the reverse build order when building the clean target (as I have blogged about [here](http://brumlemann.blogspot.com/2008/12/why-it-is-error-for-msbuild-to-build.html)). For regular build however it works nicely as described by others here.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Msbuild 4 found at c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe
It seems to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Microsoft tool that will examine all the dependencies of your 70+ projects and generate a solution file with dependencies clearly declared for you.

You have to do that on your own by using 2 different methods:

1. Manually specify a dependency, for the solution, in visual studio.
2. Specify a project reference in the project file itself.

If you don't want to do that, then you will have to swallow the medicine and accept that you will to use an external tool to do that for you. Yes it's clunky but it can be made to work. If you check in your solution file to your source control you can mitigate these problems. As long as you have an active solution file to work with.

I at one point didn't, and I had 600+ projects in the build. So I wrote a tool (years ago) that would automate 99% of this work. It uses the .NET MSBuild API's to read the msbuild files (no recreating the wheel here with xml api's). It then examines outputs and inputs and generate a dependency tree which I can then do a few things with it:

1. Spit out a solution file.
2. Do a dependency sort (also a topological sort in academia), and spit out those projects in order they should be built (for a non-parallel type of build, which can be useful sometimes).
3. print out all sorts of diagnostic information about dependencies.

The only limitation I have seen with the tool is with a few crazy COM dependencies which are pretty sketchy anyways. Which I added a super simple work-around.